# add event listener to the dynamically generated elements captured from API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an app which fetch the data from API and create a list of the books based on the data received from API. it's an API which gives book titles and information. I generated dynamic li elements and generated a button inside the li. each button has a hidden input element which keep book titles in it. the problem is I'm trying to define a onclick event listener for buttons, since buttons are generated dynamically they don't have id. I want to create an event listener for buttons so that once one specific button is clicked the value of hidden input element that is defined inside the button is passed. I couldn't figure out a way to do that. how to make it to understand which specific button has been clicked so it return the input value that is attached to it.
any help would be really appreciated.
here is a portion of my code.

```
async function overViewMaker(){
  const response = await fetch(api_url_overview.concat(api_key));
  let data = await response.json();
  data = data.results.lists;
  data.forEach(book => {
      let mybook = book.books;
      mybook.forEach(eachbook => {
      var book_div = document.getElementById('book_list');
      var liTag = document.createElement("li");
      var aTag = document.createElement("buttom");
      var inpuHidden = document.createElement("input");
      inpuHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      inpuHidden.value = eachbook.title;
      aTag.appendChild(inpuHidden);
      liTag.appendChild(aTag);
      book_div.appendChild(liTag);        
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: you would use the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) element method

Comment: by the way, to improve your code, move `var book_div = document.getElementById('book_list');` outside the forEach loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each button is already an element object and so you can use `addEventListener` directly on the element.

```js
async function overViewMaker() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url_overview.concat(api_key));
    let data = await response.json();
    data = data.results.lists;

    // moved book_div out of for loop so it doesn't need to be re-queried for every book
    var book_div = document.getElementById("book_list");

    data.forEach((book) => {
        let mybook = book.books;
        mybook.forEach((eachbook) => {
            var liTag = document.createElement("li");
            var aTag = document.createElement("button");

            var inpuHidden = document.createElement("input");
            inpuHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            inpuHidden.value = eachbook.title;
            aTag.appendChild(inpuHidden);

            aTag.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
                // you don't need to get book title from the hidden input element since it is in the scope
                // inputHidden.value is also accessible from inside of here
                const title = eachBook.title;
                console.log(title);
            });

            liTag.appendChild(aTag);
            book_div.appendChild(liTag);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution worked perfectly well.  It's taking each title when the event happens. really appreciate it.